# Fetch the KSH NAME

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, sh

```
find `pwd` -type f -name "*.ksh" -exec grep -H ".ksh" '{}' \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

On Executing this command , the result is

```
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/edw_etl_job_load.ksh:# Program Name :     edw_etl_job_load.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/edw_etl_job_load.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_housekeep_main.ksh:# Program Name     :  exec_housekeep_main.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_housekeep_main.ksh:# Called program   :  exec_housekeep.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_housekeep_main.ksh:#!/bin/ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_housekeep_main.ksh:    nohup ${SHELL_DIR}/exec_housekeep.ksh ${ROOT_ID} ${PLAN_ID} ${P_ACTION} ${LVL} &
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_housekeep_main.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/retrive_pwd_edw.ksh:#        echo "  USAGE=> filename.ksh appl_schema"
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/retrive_pwd_edw.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_pr_truncate_hkp.ksh:# Program Name     :  exec_pr_truncate_hkp.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_pr_truncate_hkp.ksh:# Calling program  :  exec_pr_truncate_hkp.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_pr_truncate_hkp.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_pr_post_housekeep.ksh:# Program Name     :  exec_pr_post_housekeep.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_pr_post_housekeep.ksh:# Calling program  :  exec_pr_post_housekeep.ksh
/home/edwprod/Partner_com/bin/exec_pr_post_housekeep.ksh
```

The command searches all the shell scripts and find the name of scripts being called inside. I need to exactly fetch the ksh name alone from this result. Please help on this?

Comment: Did you mean to use just `find \`pwd\` -type f -name "*.ksh" ` without exec?

Comment: This will give list of ksh inside the bin folder. I am trying to fetch the ksh used inside the scripts. So that If any scripts missed out, I can create before start testing / executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give this a shot (`-E` is for extended regex, `-o` is for the output only matching pattern):

```
find `pwd` -type f -name "*.ksh" -exec grep -E -o "[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.ksh" '{}' \;
```

To get a unique list:

```
find `pwd` -type f -name "*.ksh" -exec grep -E -o "[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.ksh" '{}' \; |sort -u
```

Hope this helps!